# Split function not returning anything

Tags: python, string, list, cmd, split

I am trying to make a command line, but when I use the split function and print it, it returns `[]` and it returns an error when I put it in an if statement saying `IndexError: list index out of range`.

This is my code:

```
rep = "repeat"
cmd = ""
errorColor = "\033[1;31;47m "
splitCmd = []


def cmdIn():
    cmd = input(">>")
    splitCmd = cmd.split()

cmdLen = len(cmd)
while True:
    cmdIn()
    print(splitCmd)
    if cmd == None:
        print("Error: no command entered")
    if splitCmd[0] == rep: 
        cmdArgs = ""
        for x in splitCmd:
            if splitCmd[1] == rep:
                print()
            else:
                cmdArgs += x+" "
                
    else:
        print("Unknown error")
```

Thanks, NDev

Comment: you have to return `splitCmd` from `splitCmd` funtcion if not... you will have nothing...

Comment: You actually have _two_ separate variables named `splitCmd`.  One is global, and one is local to the `cmdIn()` function.  They have no effect on each other.

Comment: ^^ same is true for `cmd`.

Comment: @John Gordon - it is already public, it is declared in the beggining

Comment: The variable inside `cmdIn()` is local, because 1) you assign to it, and 2) you did not explicitly declare it to be global.  That's just how Python works.

Answer (score -1):

Youy need to return `splitCmd` in function, and then assing then in your loop

```
rep = "repeat"
cmd = ""
errorColor = "\033[1;31;47m "
splitCmd = []


def cmdIn():
    cmd = input(">>")
    splitCmd = cmd.split()
    return splitCmd
cmdLen = len(cmd)
while True:
    splitCmd = cmdIn()
    print(splitCmd)
    if cmd == None:
        print("Error: no command entered")
    if splitCmd[0] == rep: 
        cmdArgs = ""
        for x in splitCmd:
            if splitCmd[1] == rep:
                print()
            else:
                cmdArgs += x+" "
                
    else:
        print("Unknown error")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked